# I want add one features in my existing app like iOS 10 default "NOTE" application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10

Now I don't know how to implementation this two features like iOS 10 default "NOTE" Application.

1. ToDo list
2. Add image or video

If any person know about any one of two then please share with me how to implement it.

Thanks in advance.
Please see attached image[image]

Comment: You will have better luck if you ask 1 specific question at a time, provide the code you've written and it's error message.

Comment: @Mozahler Thanks for reply, If you know about any one of three then please share with me how to implement it.

Comment: Use code data for list implementation, use any library like https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/richtexteditor  or https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Rich-Text-Editor  for rich text editing or create your own using Apple's JS framework.  

Can you please show what you have done before posting the question?